# only last added view is visible in UIScrollView iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I am facing an issue with scrollView. I have added scrollView in my storyboard as

> View
>     - MainView
>      - ScrollView
>        - accountSavingSubView

Now I am trying to add views in accountSavingSubView as below

```
    //MARK:- Create and add wallets on the UI
    private func createAndAddWallets()
    {
        var yPosition : CGFloat = 0.0
        //1. Create left hand side wallets with help of keys

        for key in dictData.keys
        {
            let walletView:Wallet = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("Wallet", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! Wallet
            walletView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            walletView.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: yPosition, width: accountSavingSubView.frame.width, height: accountSavingSubView.frame.height)
            walletView.accountNameLabel.text = key
            accountSavingSubView.addSubview(walletView)
            yPosition += walletView.frame.maxY
            walletView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            print("walletView frame is :\(walletView.frame)")
        }
        //set continer scroll content size
            self.contanerScrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.accountSavingSubView.frame.width, height: CGFloat(80.0/320.0)*UIScreen.main.bounds.width*CGFloat(self.dictData.keys.count))
}
```

Where dictData is a dictionary of ([String: String]).

But in my view, I can see only last view is added on (x=0, y=0). ScrollView content size is correct & I can scroll without having views except last one at first place(x:0,y:0).

Please let me know what am I doing wrong here in my code while adding views.

Answer (score 0):

You need to comment this

```
walletView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

as it's used with setting constraints only ,and verify that the supplied frame values here are not 0

```
walletView.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: yPosition, width: accountSavingSubView.frame.width, height: accountSavingSubView.frame.height)
```

btw you can also comment it as the frame will be captured as you set it in xib if you make it freedom size